# Rational bezier curves and pdfs

Tags: projective-geometry, bezier-curve

My goal is to write out the 2D projection of a 3D bezier curve to a pdf document.

I am told that the 2D perspective (conic) projection of a 3D bezier curve is a rational bezier curve. There are instructions on how to compute the projected control points.

The PDF specification says that bezier curves are described with control and anchor points which are evaluated via the explicit form of the cubic bezier.

What I don't understand is how to re-cast the rational bezier curve such that it is expressible in the way PDF expects.

Comment: PDF's Path object does not support rational Bezier curve. You will have to approximate the rational Bezier curve by a series of cubic Bezier curves or straight lines.

Comment: Thanks @fang I will now search for that literature!